# How to handle \section* with asterisk in my custom class

Tags: sectioning, document-classes, starred-version

I've redefined sections and subsections in my .cls file in such a way that \section* results in bad behavior.

For example, `\section*{Introduction} These analyses were performed` in my .tex file results in:

[image]

I know that I should fix this using something like the `\@ifstar` functionality discussed here : https://texfaq.org/FAQ-cmdstar . However, after a few hours and many iterations, I haven't succeeded. Do any of you know what I'm missing?

The sections and subsections are redefined thusly in my .cls file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%% SECTIONING %%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection%
{section}{1}{\z@}%      %name, level, indent
{-\baselineskip}%       %beforeskip
{.75\baselineskip}%     %afterskip
{\reset@font\bf\MakeUppercase}  %bold, uppercase
}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\@Roman\c@section} 

\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection%
{subsection}{2}{\z@}%       %name, level, indent
{-\baselineskip}%       %beforeskip
{.75\baselineskip}%     %afterskip
{\reset@font\bf}%               %bold
}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\@Alph\c@subsection}

\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection
{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%    %name, level, indent
{-.75\baselineskip}%        %beforeskip
{.5\baselineskip}%      %afterskip
{\reset@font\emph}%             %italic
}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\@roman\c@subsection}
```

I have put a minimal working example online. It contains three files and a pdf.

min_ex.tex : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10060444/min_ex/min_ex.tex
ntmanuscript.cls : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10060444/min_ex/ntmanuscript.cls
min_ex.pdf : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10060444/min_ex/min_ex.pdf

Comment: I think my question was very clear, though I didn't use a question mark. I said "I hope one of you knows what I'm missing."

Comment: I'll change the sentence to use a question mark, if that's easier for you to understand. Dan, below, clearly understood the question just fine.

Comment: You may be better off using the `titlesec` package instead of using low-level stuff like `\@startsection`, etc.

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks. That was noted below by Dan as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to add any `\@ifstar` to your definitions, because `\@startsection` already takes care of that. However, some package you are using redefines `\@ifstar`. For some reason this redefinition uses `\new@ifnextchar` rather than the standard `\@ifnextchar`. The old definition would ignore spaces, but this new one does not. You have introduces a space between the end of `\@startsection` and the asterisk:

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection%
  {section}{1}{\z@}%      %name, level, indent
  {-\baselineskip}%       %beforeskip
  {.75\baselineskip}%     %afterskip
  {\reset@font\bf\MakeUppercase}  %bold, uppercase
}
```

See it there in the line `{\reset@font\bf\MakeUppercase}  %bold, uppercase` before the percent sign. Change that to  `{\reset@font\bf\MakeUppercase}% bold, uppercase`.

Since you are loading the titlesec package, I don't understand why you have chosen to use the low-level LaTeX interface `\@atartsection`. Shouldn't you be using `titlesec`'s facilities for changing the appearance of section titles?

Comment: Thanks Dan! That fixed it. I didn't realize the % signs were so important! I thought it was a style choice rather than a functional syntax! Silly me.

Comment: Also, concerning your question about titlesec, the short answer is that I didn't know any better! I'll look into how I can use titlesec features instead of \@startsection . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note how all the default sectional units define their fonts as *switches* (from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

In your class you're using *macros* (`\MakeUppercase` and `\emph`), not *switches*. These macros grab the first argument they can and could potentially grab the wrong information during the expansion of `\@startsection`. Also, to avoid `\@ifstar` problems, don't leave spaces inside your sectional definitions. Here's what you should *add* to your class:

```
\RequirePackage{regexpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch
\newcommand{\@sec@title@format}[1]{#1}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\@sect}{#8}{\@sec@title@format{#8}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\@ssect}{#5}{\@sec@title@format{#5}}{}{}
\makeatletter
```

And your definitions of sectional units should resemble:

```
%%%%%%%%%%% SECTIONING %%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\section}{\renewcommand{\@sec@title@format}[1]{\MakeUppercase{##1}}%
  \@startsection%
    {section}{1}{\z@}%      %name, level, indent
    {-\baselineskip}%       %beforeskip
    {.75\baselineskip}%     %afterskip
    {\reset@font\bfseries}%  %bold, uppercase
}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\@Roman\c@section} 

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\renewcommand{\@sec@title@format}[1]{##1}%
  \@startsection%
      {subsection}{2}{\z@}%     %name, level, indent
      {-\baselineskip}%     %beforeskip
      {.75\baselineskip}%       %afterskip
      {\reset@font\bfseries}%               %bold
}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\@Alph\c@subsection}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\renewcommand{\@sec@title@format}[1]{\emph{##1}}%
  \@startsection
    {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%    %name, level, indent
    {-.75\baselineskip}%        %beforeskip
    {.5\baselineskip}%      %afterskip
    {\reset@font}%             %italic
}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\@roman\c@subsection}
```

Comment: I appreciate this response, as it's clear that you're listing a number of things that are potentially bad about my class file. However, I prefer the simplest solution. Since just removing the space before the % sign, as Dan above suggested was sufficient, I've chosen his as the "answer." Thanks for your response though!